# simple xml object

Tags: php, session

hello i'm trying to save the values of a SimpleXMLElement to a $_SESSION but the values are entered as "SimpleXMLElement Object". code below:

```
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($auth_info);
$_SESSION[userName] = $xml->profile->preferredUsername; (garfx)
$_SESSION[email] =  $xml->profile->verifiedEmail;
$_SESSION[givenName] =  $xml->profile->name->givenName;
$_SESSION[lastName] =  $xml->profile->name->familyName;
```

results example

```
Array
(
[userName] => SimpleXMLElement Object
()
)
```

i would like

```
Array
(
[userName] => garfx

)
```

Comment: try casting them to strings like `$_SESSION['givenName'] = (string) $xml->profile->name->givenName`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

SimpleXML elements can be used as strings, but you need to "cast" them to a string.

Casting in PHP is done by prefixing the data type to a value,

so for example,

```
$foo = 1;
$bar = (string)$foo;
```

Would make `$bar` be a string containing the character "1".

The solution for the above would be:-

```
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($auth_info);
$_SESSION[userName] = (string)$xml->profile->preferredUsername; // (garfx)
$_SESSION[email] = (string)$xml->profile->verifiedEmail;
$_SESSION[givenName] = (string)$xml->profile->name->givenName;
$_SESSION[lastName] = (string)$xml->profile->name->familyName;
```

Answer (score 1):

Cast it as a `(string)`

```
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($auth_info);
$_SESSION[userName] = (string)$xml->profile->preferredUsername;
$_SESSION[email] = (string)$xml->profile->verifiedEmail;
$_SESSION[givenName] = (string)$xml->profile->name->givenName;
$_SESSION[lastName] = (string) $xml->profile->name->familyName;
```